# How to tell "School" from "Work" account in Microsoft AD OAuth 2 authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How to tell "School" from "Work" account when authenticating a user in Microsft Graph?

Based on [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit),  I can use the tenant ID to separate "Work and School" from personal accounts.

In my case, it is also important to separate business users from students/teachers.

Is there some information in the identity claims or another way to say if the account is a "school" account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "Work/School Account" isn't an actual account designation or type. It's purely used to describe organizational accounts and personal accounts.

There is no distinction between a "Work" or "School" account as they both describe the same thing, an Azure AD User.

If you need to determine if a given user in a single tenant is a Student, Teacher or Administrator then you would need to establish a convention for how they are designated. One convention might be to establish separate security groups and add each user to their respective group.